# Javascript not executing when right clicked into new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my simple code

```
 function goto() {
        /* Some code to be executed */
        if (a == "1")
              location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        else
              location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
```

And here is html

```
<a href="#" onclick="goto();">Hello</a>
```

this works perfectly fine when i click normally but if i right click it and open in a new tab it doesn't execute.

Comment: That's correct. Opening in new tab is not a `click` event.

Comment: "click" event fires only when the left mouse button is clicked on the element :=
)

Comment: right click does not trigger the click event :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<a href="javascript:goto()">Hello</a>

 function goto() {
        /* Some code to be executed */
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

if you want to open in new tab on mouse right click,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a>
```

hit mouse right click and open in new tab

**OR**

u can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function goto() {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                goto();
            });
            document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
                goto();
            });
        }, false)

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked on a middle-mouse click for me, but not open in new tab.

Comment: well this won't work since i'm setting redirect url conditionally inside the javascript function.Cannot set in the href.Updated my question

Comment: y dont u just change the url of anchor tag in the javascript function

Comment: well it is not always a new tab or a new window.It can be right click or left  click depending on what user does

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="myId">Hello</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev){
    gotoFunc(ev);
});

function gotoFunc(ev){
    //run this when right clicked over #myId element
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
 function changeDest(elem) {
        /* Some code to be executed */
        if (a == "1")
              elem.href = "http://www.google.com";
        else
              elem.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }

 <a href="#" onmousedown="changeDest(this);">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can instead use `<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="goto();">Hello</a>`
This should do the trick. i.e adding the url to the href of the anchor tag